# How to change DayOfWeek() to start from own day

Tags: coldfusion, calendar, coldfusion-9, cfml, dayofweek

I want to change the `DayOfWeek()` function so that I can get dates according to my own desired first day of the week. So what I am doing in this code is that I am setting a `startDate`, `endDate` and `selectDays` that I want to check. Here is my code:

```
<cfscript>

function Mydayofweek(date, day_1)
{   
    return (((DayOfWeek(date) + (7 -day_1)) MOD 7) +1);
}

</cfscript>

<cfset startDate = '07/01/2013'>
<cfset endDate = '07/25/2013'>
<Cfset mydates = ''>
<cfset selectDays = '2,6'>

<cfset MyWeekFirstDay = 6> <!---I selected Friday = 6 --->
<cfset new = ''>

<cfoutput>
    <cfloop list="#selectDays#" delimiters="," index="d">
        <cfset new &=  '#Mydayofweek(d, MyWeekFirstDay)#,' >
    </cfloop>


<cfif new NEQ ''>
    <cfset ScheduleDate = left(new, (len(new)-1) )>
</cfif>

<cfdump var="#ScheduleDate#"><br />
</cfoutput>
<cfset AppendToMyDates = false>
 <cfloop from="#startDate#" to="#endDate#" index="day">
 <cfif AppendToMyDates is false and DayOfWeek(day) is ListFirst(selectDays)>
 <cfset AppendToMyDates = true>
 </cfif>

    <cfif listfind(ScheduleDate, DayOfWeek(day), ',') NEQ 0 and AppendToMyDates is true>

      <cfset mydates &= "#dateformat(day, 'mmm, dd, yyyy dddd')#,<br />">

    </cfif>
    </cfloop><cfoutput>#mydates#</cfoutput>
```

This is written in ColdFusion.  That code generates this output:

```
4,1
Jul, 03, 2013 Wednesday,
Jul, 07, 2013 Sunday,
Jul, 10, 2013 Wednesday,
Jul, 14, 2013 Sunday,
Jul, 17, 2013 Wednesday,
Jul, 21, 2013 Sunday,
Jul, 24, 2013 Wednesday,
```

The Output Should be like this because i select Friday = 1 to Thursday = 7 so the above days `selectDays = '2,6'` should now point to selectDays = '7,4' with respect to my first days `2,6`

```
7,4
Jul, 06, 2013 Saturday,
Jul, 10, 2013 Wednesday,
Jul, 13, 2013 Saturday,
Jul, 17, 2013 Wednesday,
Jul, 20, 2013 Saturday,
Jul, 24, 2013 Wednesday,
```

I have set my `selectDays = '2,6'` it means I want to get dates of `Saturday` and `Wednesday` because I have set 6 as my week first day and it start from Friday (by default it was sunday). My days start from Sunday `Sunday = 1 , Monday = 2 , Tuesday = 3 , Wednesday = 4 , Thursday = 5 , Friday = 6 , Saturday = 7` and now I changed my date start from `Friday = 1 , Saturday = 2 ,Sunday = 3 , Monday = 4 , Tuesday = 5 , Wednesday = 6 , Thursday = 7` in script function. Actually I think there is error in my script function that i don't understand. Please help me out to find the problem and it's solution thanks

### UPDATED

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but changing the behaviour of the DayOfWeek() function will not help you achieve your goal.  Basically you have to add some if/else logic inside your loop to not write a Wednesday to your mydates variable if it is empty.

Comment: The first day of DayOfWeek is already Sunday: "The ordinal for the day of the week, as an integer in the range 1 (Sunday) to 7 (Saturday)."  Not sure why you'd want to change its functionality in this case

Comment: @DanBracuk can u tell me what will be the right if/else condition

Comment: I still think you are over-complicating your issue. Don't worry about changing the default day values. Your code can handle the user's selection and then set the function to the appropriate value behind the scenes. If a user wants their week to begin on Tuesday, then just have your code make the appropriate selection of "3" for them. I don't think you really need to change the functionality otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call your script into your loop. No need to make any function just change the code like this one.
Copy this code hope this will solve your problem.

```
<cfscript>
  function Mydayofweek(date, day_1)
  {   
     return (((DayOfWeek(date) + (7 -day_1)) MOD 7) +1);
  } 
</cfscript>

<cfset startDate = '07/01/2013'>
<cfset endDate = '07/25/2013'>
<Cfset mydates = ''>
<cfset selectDays = '2,6'>
<cfset MyWeekFirstDay = 6><!---I selected Friday = 6 --->


<cfloop from="#startDate#" to="#endDate#" index="day">
  <cfif listfind(selectDays, Mydayofweek(day,MyWeekFirstDay), ',') NEQ 0 >
    <cfset mydates &= "#dateformat(day, 'mmm, dd, yyyy dddd')#,<br />">
  </cfif>
</cfloop>
<cfoutput>#mydates#</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 1):

With the new information that selectDays might not always be the same, I'd do something like this:

```
<cfset AppendToMyDates = false>
 <cfloop from="#startDate#" to="#endDate#" index="day">
 <cfif AppendToMyDates is false and DayOfWeek(day) is ListFirst(SelectDays)>
 <cfset AppendToMyDates = true>
 </cfif>

    <cfif listfind(selectDays, DayOfWeek(day), ',') NEQ 0 and AppendToMyDates is true>
      <cfset mydates &= "#dateformat(day, 'mmm, dd, yyyy dddd')#,<br />">
    </cfif>
  </cfloop>
```

**Edit starts here**

If you want the start of the week to be a variable, you want to write your own version of DayOfWeek() with a different name.  The structure would be something like this:

```
<cffunction name="DayOfWeekModified returntype="numeric">
<cfargument name="WeekStartsOn" type="numeric" required="yes">
<cfscript>
var DayNumber = 0;
code to generate it based on arguments.WeekStartsOn
return DayNumber;
<cfscript>
<cffunction>
```

You then call this function instead of DayOfWeek() in your loop.

Comment: is the boolean necessary? Why not just put `DayOfWeek(day) is ListFirst(SelectDays)` in the 2nd if statement as the and?

Comment: If I did that, I think it would never add values for the second list item.

Comment: @DanBracuk thanks , your answer helps me a little bit to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is with your `cfif` condition. You are looping over the dates and then checking if the given date is a Wednesday or Friday and the results you are getting are correct.  Since you want to start with a Friday (ignoring the first Wednesday) you need to add that to your code.  This may work for you:

```
<cfset startDate = '06/11/2013'>
<cfset endDate = '06/25/2013'>
<cfset mydates = ''>
<cfset selectDays = '6,4'>

<cfloop from="#startDate#" to="#endDate#" index="day">
    <cfif listfind(selectDays, DayOfWeek(day), ',') NEQ 0>
        <cfif mydates NEQ "" OR DayOfWeek(day) EQ "6">
            <cfset mydates &= "#dateformat(day, 'mmm, dd, yyyy dddd')#,<br />">
        </cfif>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
<cfoutput>#mydates#</cfoutput>
```

I added an additional `cfif` condition around the setting of `mydates`.  This code `mydates NEQ ""` is checking to see if `mydates` is not empty, meaning we have already satisified the next condition.  If `mydates` is empty then also check to see if the given date is a Friday with `DayOfWeek(day) EQ "6"`. This should guarantee that the first date entered in `mydates` is a Friday.

Not sure how I feel about this code but it seemed to work for me with your example.

Comment: it works in case but if i give `<cfset selectDays = '2,3'>` then it fails

Comment: That is correct. That is why I don't like this solution. You will need to change the code for different days. Just change the `DayOfWeek(day) EQ "6"` condition to be the first day of the week you want to begin with.  So instead of `"6"` for Friday, change to `"2"` for Monday, etc.

Comment: actual I mean to say that I want to fix my starting day of week and then according that fix day I want to display my date. for example today date's starting week day is  `06/23/2013 Sunday` and I want to find out my desired day are `<selectDays = '2,3'>` it means `Saturday and Sunday` according to my fix day. Now my dayes will start from `friday = 1` to `Thursday = 7` so this is my actual problem

Comment: I understand less than I did earlier, but you still don't want to change a cf native function.  Maybe a user defined function is the way to go.

Comment: @AzamAlvi - I am afraid I don't understand your last comment either? I don't think you can change the starting day of the week for the built-in ColdFusion functions; 1=Sunday. So you will need to work with that. I don't understand why you keep changing your `selectDays`? It seems as though even your own starting day of the week is changing?

Comment: @Miguel-F I m developing a calendar in which user can change his own starting day of the week that's y i want to change this function

Comment: @AzamAlvi - Thanks for the explanation. It looks like Dan took my example a little further and made it work with whatever values you have in your `selectDays` list. Seems like his answer will work for you.